# Send current location in Messages app running iOS 12

Tags: ios, messages, geolocation

In older versions of iOS, the Messages app had an `i` character in a circle which allowed us to send our current location to the other person. The location could be one-time snapshot of location, or a location updateable for a certain amount of time.

The i-in-circle is gone in current iOS.

Can I send current location in Messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Tap recipient’s name > `info` button > `Send My Current Location` (or `Share…`)

Sure, It's just two taps away. But it's not visible, so you wouldn't know it by looking.

Tap the name under the icon for your contact in details. (this tap target it pretty small, so you might miss it first time you try)

The panel expands to display `audio`, `FaceTime`, and `info` buttons. Tap the `info` button to display a panel with several items. One of this items is the option to send current location, either snapshot or ongoing.

[image: messages details on iOS]

Then tap, Send My Current Location (this one is thankfully easy to tap)

[image: send my current location control]